# React Environment Variables

Tags: reactjs

I created an react using the link here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

I installed nothing after this
I want to create a .env file but it is not registering
I followed this example: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

I created a file that was called `.env` and `.env.development`

The application will not read an environment variable file.

Here is my app.tsx file that updated

```
import './App.css';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
          {process.env.NODE_ENV}< br />
          {process.env.REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My .env and .env.development files contain this:

```
REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE=SecertCode
```

Comment: strange. make sure that .env  and .env.development files are at the root level of your project. Also make sure you restart the server.